# How to hide action name from url in struts2

Tags: jboss, url-rewriting, struts2

As you see from the title, the problem is:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVLET_PATH} ^/(.+) 
RewriteRule ^/(.+)  /home.action [L]
```

-> then if I type domain.com/blahblah the home.action will be executed

However if:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVLET_PATH} ^/
RewriteRule ^/  /home.action [L]
```

-> then I type domain.com -> home.action never be executed!

I used an index.jsp (and declare in web.xml as well) and add:

```
response.sendRedirect("home.action");
```

DIDN'T work

Then add:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="1;URL=home.action">
```

DIDN'T work

As a result, I would be appreciated to hear your solutions in order to execute an action by only type the domain url without any path. Such as: domain.com

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your app using a context path?

Comment: in application.xml there is <context-root>/</context-root> if that is what you ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**;

Don't write a condition, just only this ->

```
RewriteRule ^/index$  /home.action [L]
```

And your index.jsp should be:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-9" />
    <meta name="verify-v1" content="tonewfwefwewfwefwefrz4tqvroPwefewfy3izuwefwefKs=" />  
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=" /> 
</head>
<body>  
  <%
  response.setStatus(301); 
  response.setHeader( "Location", "/" );
  response.setHeader( "Connection", "close" );  
  %>    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a root context. Therefore, would it be safe to say that you would normally access your action by going to `http://www.domain.com/home.action`?

If so, then you can configure `HomeAction` as the default action in your struts.xml.

**Example**

```
<action name="home" class="...">
    ...
</action>

<default-action-ref name="home"/>
```

Then, if you request just `http://www.example.com/`, it should invoke your home action.

Comment: Hi, at first thanks. However, to my opinion, the default action enables us to set a default action that will be executed if we dont declare a class in an action definition. So unfortunately it didnt solve my problem.

Comment: If it didn't resolve your problem, what is happening when you go to domain.com ?

Comment: only index.jsp is appeared when I go to domain.com

Comment: Anyways, many thanks for your attention and help, I have found a solution in a number of try, shared it below.